# Highcharts view data table is showing incorrect data

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am building this application in angular5.

The sample code is shown below. The data consists of a time/category (string) and an integer value.

When I use integer values instead of a string in place of category, it is working fine. But it should work for daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly.

---

```
var data1 =[["Q2-15", 40.4],
["Q3-15", 40.7],
["Q4-15", 40.5],
["Q1-16", 41.4],
["Q2-16", 41.4],
["Q3-16", 41.4],
["Q4-16", 40.8],
["Q1-17", 41],
["Q2-17", 41.4],
["Q3-17", 41.2],
["Q4-17", 42],
["Q1-18", 42.9],
["Q2-18", 42.9],
["Q3-18", 42.9],
["Q4-18", 42.9],
["Q1-19", 42.3],
["Q2-19", 44.7],
["Q3-19", 45.5],
["Q4-19", 14.6],
["Q1-20", 36.6]],

data2=[["Q1-20", 36.6],
["Q2-20", 83.2],
["Q3-20", 55.3]],

data3 = [
["Q4-19", 149.6, 149.6],
["Q1-20", 19.9, 52.4],
["Q2-20", 67.4, 100.02],
["Q3-20", 39.5, 72.13]
],    

data4 = [
["Q4-19", 14.6, 14.6],
["Q1-20", 24.4, 47.8],
["Q2-20", 72.06, 94.4],
["Q3-20", 44.17, 67.5]
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
text: "Forecast Chart"
},
xAxis: {
type: 'category'
},
yAxis: {
title: null,
},
series: [{
name: "data1",
data: data1,
type: 'spline',
color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
zIndex: 1,
marker: {
fillColor: 'white',
lineWidth: 2,
lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
}
},
{
name: "data2",
data: data2,
type: 'spline',
color: "#4781c1",
zIndex: 1,
marker: {
fillColor: 'white',
symbol: 'circle',
lineWidth: 2,
lineColor: "#4781c1"
}
},
{
name: "data3",
data: data3,
type: 'arearange',
lineWidth: 0,
linkedTo: ':previous',
color: '#7cbaff',
marker: {
enabled: false
}
},
{
name: "data4",
data: data4,
type: 'arearange',
lineWidth: 0,
linkedTo: ':previous',
color: '#b8d8fb',
marker: {
enabled: false
}
}
],
responsive: {
rules: [{
condition: {
maxWidth: 500
},
chartOptions: {
legend: {
layout: 'horizontal',
align: 'center',
verticalAlign: 'bottom'
}
}
}]
},
exporting: {
buttons: {
contextButton: {
symbol: 'download',
symbolStroke: "",
symbolStrokeWidth: 5,
menuItems: ["viewFullscreen", "downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "downloadPDF", "downloadXLS", "viewData"]
}
}
},
navigation: {
menuItemHoverStyle: {
background: '#f1f1f1',
color: 'black'
}
}
});
```

---

[JsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce7qf0a6/1/)

---

**Sample Chart**

[image: Sample Chart]

---

**Chart-Table View**

[image: Chart-Table view]

Comment: Clarified the question; grouped links for JSFiddle and Images; made images display inline.

Answer (score 0):

Reply from HighCharts Forum at https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=43528&p=153676#p153676

> We are aware of this bug and we are working on solving this issue. You
>   can watch for the update here:
>   https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12767
>
> You can work around this issue by setting missing data to an empty
>   array as I did it in the demo below.
>   **Live demo:** jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g5fykpnm/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.